# Error : does not match the corresponding name on disk, REACT

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I have this error :
./src/pages/Freelances/index.jsx
Cannot find file: 'index.jsx' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\Card\Components'.
And I honnestly don't undersatand why.

My code is :

```
import Card from '../../components/Card'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import colors from '../../utils/style/colors'
import React from 'react'

const CardsContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  gap: 24px;
  grid-template-rows: 350px 350px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
`

const PageTitle = styled.h1`
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
`

const PageSubtitle = styled.h2`
  font-size: 20px;
  color: ${colors.secondary};
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
`

const freelanceProfiles = [
  {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    jobTitle: 'Devops',
  },
  {
    name: 'John Doe',
    jobTitle: 'Developpeur frontend',
  },
  {
    name: 'Jeanne Biche',
    jobTitle: 'Développeuse Fullstack',
  },
]

function Freelances() {
  return (
    <div>
      <PageTitle>Trouvez votre prestataire</PageTitle>
      <PageSubtitle>
        Chez Shiny nous réunissons les meilleurs profils pour vous.
      </PageSubtitle>
      <CardsContainer>
        {freelanceProfiles.map((profile, index) => (
          <Card
            key={`${profile.name}-${index}`}
            label={profile.jobTitle}
            title={profile.name}
          />
        ))}
      </CardsContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Freelances
```

And if I take back the import react from react i have this error :
./src/pages/Freelances/index.jsx
Line 46:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 47:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 48:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 51:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 53:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

I just want to use a code that was working in a TP into somthing else. Do you know what caused this error?

Comment: That error pops up when the capitalization of your files doesn't match the capitalization of your import statements

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed an error in the 1rst line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure you have imported `React` in all the files that have jsx. Like, `import React from 'react'`  It might also be required by your build system that files with jsx have `.jsx` or `.tsx` extensions (not just `.js` / `.ts`)
2. Ensure that file names that are referenced in your code are matching actual file names in a filesystem. There could be issues if file names had changes in capitalization. Keeping file names in lowercase might be a good idea to avoid such sort of problems