# My app keeps failing to compile after running npm start

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting this error messages although i have imported React

Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Line 6:5:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 7:7:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 8:9:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 9:9:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 10:16:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
Line 12:9:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

=======Here's a code in my app.js========

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SideMenu from "../components/SideMenu";
import Home from '../pages/Home.js';
import Table from '../pages/Table.js';
import { makeStyles, CssBaseline, createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider 
} from '@material-ui/core';
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react- 
router-dom";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
palette: {
primary: {
  main: "#333996",
  light: '#3c44b126'
},
secondary: {
  main: "#f83245",
  light: '#f8324526'
},
background: {
  default: "#f4f5fd"
},
},
 overrides:{
 MuiAppBar:{
   root:{
     transform:'translateZ(0)'
   }
 }
 },
  props:{
   MuiIconButton:{
   disableRipple:true
  }
  }
 })


const useStyles = makeStyles({
 appMain: {
 paddingLeft: '320px',
 width: '100%'
}
})

function App() {
const classes = useStyles();

 return (
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  
  <Router>
  <SideMenu />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/table" element={<Table />} />
   
    </Routes>
  
  </Router>
  <div className={classes.appMain}>
    <Header />

    
    
   </div>
    <Footer />
   <CssBaseline />
  </ThemeProvider>
 );
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: Try to reinstall packages. Remove node_modules and run `yarn install` or `npm install`. Reload your local server.

Comment: Did that , didn't work

Comment: Can you show your package.json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : does not match the corresponding name on disk, REACT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72046113/error-does-not-match-the-corresponding-name-on-disk-react)